# How can I do slideDown or slideUp in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

This my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function () {
 $('a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('div').slideUp();
   $("#box_" + $(this).attr("href")).slideDown();
   $(this).addClass("active");
   return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.hide{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="01">Open Box 01</a>
    <div id="box_01" class="hide">
     Box 01
    </div>
    <a href="02">Open Box 02</a>
    <div id="box_02" class="hide">
     Box 02
    </div>
```

Comment: create a directive, write all that DOM manipulation inside the link function, and add the directive to the anchor element

Comment: with relations to the comment by NoDownvotesPlz - you might want to check this tutorial about it from [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-basic-behaviors)

Comment: Dear @SWLim isn't clear to me...I'm new in AngularJs

Comment: No worries, I was new to AngularJS about a week ago! I highly suggest you start with this [short intro course by CodeSchool](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro).
Then you would want to move onto [eggHead tutorials](https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs?order=ASC) :) then attempt to tackle the obstacle you have posted.

Comment: No problem, this platform is made for providing guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to look into the [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), the angular animation library.

[This](http://ng.malsup.com/#!/css-animations-for-ng-hide_ng-show) is a good tutorial.